# Как назвать файл для перехода по ссылке?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select, jquery-form, queryselector

Когда я выбираю 3 пункта и нажимаю кнопку меня перебрасывает на адрес, я хочу что бы под этим адресом была страница, но я не понимаю как мне назвать файл или отредактировать ссылку, что бы я мог задавать страницу например "audi-r82001.php"

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
 var mark = $("#mark-select option:selected").val();
 var model = $("#model-select option:selected").val();
 var age = $("#age-select option:selected").val();
 if(mark != 'Марка' && model != 'Модель' && age != 'Поколение') {
   location.href = "http://localhost/?mark="+ mark + "&model="+ model +"&age="+ age;
  // или вариант в новом окне
  // window.open("http://localhost/?mark="+ mark + "&model="+ model +"&age="+ age);

  console.log("http://localhost/?mark="+ mark + "&model="+ model +"&age="+ age);
 }
 return false;
});
```

```html
<select id="mark-select"></select>
<select id="model-select"></select>
<select id="age-select"></select>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Перейти</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var url = "http://localhost/" + mark + "-" + model + age + ".php";    
console.log(url);
location.href = url;
```

Что выводит в консоль такой код:

```
console.log(`[${mark}]-[${model}]-[${age}]`);
```

Comment: Когда я нажимаю перейти формируется ссылка -  http://localhost:8888/Audi-R8R8%202001.php , я называю файл "Audi-R8R8%202001.php"  и все равно не работает, меня отправляет на главную страницу

Comment: `%20` - это пробел.

Comment: Ого, спасибо огромное, мне еще учиться и учиться)